# anyone have solution for this error " TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int' "

Tags: python, flask

i wanted to fetch the data(blob) to download it from my database. I'm facing some error with bytes **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'**, I had been working on this for so long.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if not request.form.get("search"):

            return error("error")

        conn= sqlite3.connect("YTD2.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        c = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")

        id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name=:name", \
                        name=request.form.get("search"))
        # print(data)
        for sub in id:
            for key in sub:
                sub[key] = int(sub[key])

        for x in c.fetchall():
            data_v=x[1][sub[key]]
            break
        
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        # print(c)    
        return send_file(BytesIO(data_v), attachment_filename='download.pdf', as_attachment=True)
    
    return redirect("home.html")
```

here is the error

```
DEBUG:cs50:SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name='网格.pdf'
ERROR:app:Exception on /search [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "e:\programme\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Win X\Desktop\CS50 FP\TRY\Download Prob\app.py", line 176, in search
    return send_file(BytesIO(data_v), attachment_filename='download.jpg', as_attachment=True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2020 23:44:12] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

*anyone else have some good algorithm to flask blob from database and store as PDF, i had been working on this using flask_wtf*

Answer (score 0):

`db.execute` returns a list of rows, even if the result only contains one row. If you are only expecting one result, index the list first.

```
id = id[0]
```

Comment: id[0] doesn;t work, so i used loop and it work well, thankss

Answer (score 0):

Use id[0] or a loop to iterate over the id. Because `db.execute` will return an iterable.
Although if db.execute's query will return one row for you it will be like `id=[[xxxxxx]]`.

> So use id[0] to print. Or use a loop.

Comment: id[0] doesn;t work, so i used loop and it work well, thankss

Comment: Sure. Goodluck. Hope the soultion I gave helped.